# CSS/Javascript show image remove x on mouseover/hover

Tags: html, css, positioning

I would like to have a picture like:

[image: http://www.clker.com/cliparts/q/P/p/c/m/r/gray-x-mark-md.png]

I'd like it displayed in the top right corner of each of my images, 5px from the right and top of the image. I have the functions for showing and hiding the x as well as removing the appropriate elements, but I'm very bad with CSS positioning and I don't know how to get it to show in the top right corner.

code so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/eetwL/

Comment: Please include your actual code so we can help you modify it rather than write it for you from scratch.

Comment: ok, here's what I have from the answers: http://jsfiddle.net/eetwL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be a piece of cake! You can position that element `absolute`, which means that it'll not flow with the layout but will instead get its position based off that of it's nearest relative parent. Let's pretend you have that "x" in an anchor, like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <a class="close" href="#">x</a>
</div>
```

You would want to make sure that there's a relative parent somewhere. This will be the starting point from which your `top` and `right` CSS rules will be applied. To make the anchor 5px from the top right of the container...

```
div.container {
    position: relative;
    // possibly important to set width, height, etc.
}

a.close {
    // set size, background image, etc.
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one relatively simple way to do it. Basically, you can set an element to `position:absolute` and control its top, right, bottom, and left positions if its parent is `position:relative;`.

```
<div class="img">
    <img src="whatever.jpg"/>

    <img class="xmark" src="gra-x-mark-md.png"/>
</div>

<style>
.img{
    position:relative;
}
.img .xmark{
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This isn't working though, it just puts the x all the way to the right of the screen.

Comment: You need to make sure the parent element has `position: relative;`, or anything except `position: static;` which is the default.

Comment: The `<div class="img">` will be as wide as the containing element, so the `x` could be on the very right on the window. I suspect there will be an answer update soon...

Comment: I remember looking up how to have an element take the shape of its contents and finding that there wasn't a way.

Comment: If it is not a  block level element, you won't have this issue. IE, if it is a `<span>` element, it will fit the content on the inside of the element. but this has other implications, so be sure you are aware of that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Block-level_elements

Comment: @user828584:  You will have to make the wrapper or parent container `<div>` the same width as the image within.  Otherwise, use the upper-left corner for your `X` button image.